# Looking for some good sources to read on creating ArrayLists(in Java) methods from scratch

Tags: java

I looked everywhere but there are only tutorials on how to work with already provided to us Array Lists by Java API. We are going through collections in school right now and this semester is required from us(part of it) to be able to create collections(Linked lists, Array Lists etc.) methods from scratch. I was wondering if you guys can recommend me some good sources to read on creating ArrayLists methods from scratch because we don't get almost any explanation in class, we just get the exercise.

Comment: Why do you have to create it from scratch? You might want to look at the code already written if you want the insides.

Comment: For learning. But I can't find an already written code on internet either. Is there a way to view the code of the Java API in Eclipse?

Comment: There are plugins available in the Marketplace. If you are working with Eclipse then you might want to look at JadClipse.

Comment: Tutorials about those things are just one web-search away... Those exercises most likely contain some keywords describing the data structure; Identify those and use google, bing, or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick up any book on data-structures and algorithms.. These books will teach you how to write ArrayLists, LinkedLists etc.. as well as when to use them.

However, if you want to just look at how Java implements collections, just hold down CTRL and click on the collection you want to view in Eclipse. This should take you to the collection's source code.